# Chrome extension: sendResponse not working properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am taking a screenshot of the viewport using chrome extension's inbuilt function. In the background script, when a message is received for the capture of the screenshot, I capture it and send the `dataURI` back to the origin using sendResponse. When I `console.log` of the URI in the background script, it's perfectly fine, but when I receive the response in origin script, it turns out to be undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request,sender,sendResponse) {
    console.log("huf");
    if(request.capture) {
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {}, function(dataUrl) {
                if(dataUrl) {
                    console.log(dataUrl);
                    sendResponse({"screenshot":dataUrl});           
                }
            });
        });
    }
    return true;
});
```

Content script:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"capture":true},function(response) {
    console.log(response.screenshot);
});
```

Comment: @wOxxOm That is not the case.

Comment: Tried your code to reproduce the issue. The code works. Try reloading the extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is it possible that some other component of my code is responsible for this?

Comment: @wOxxOm i have tried everything from reloading the extension to reinstalling it. Did every such possible measure.

Comment: That leaves you the only way out: comment out everything except the posted code, ensure it works, uncomment back in chunks until it fails.

Comment: @wOxxOm I'll do that. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: It would also help if you included your manifest; specifically permissions and content scripts part (if any).

Comment: Note: Your `return true` should be inside the `if` block. As you know, returning true indicates that you are going to be asynchronously sending a response using `sendResponse`. You don't intend to send a response unless `request.capture` is truthy. Thus, you should only return true (to keep the channel open) from within the `if` block

Comment: I was able to solve this by commenting out the irrelevant portion of my code. As it turns out some other part of my code was messing up the response. There was another sendRespnose function which was sending a response and javascript being asychronous, that response was being sent first.

Comment: Also, the callback function should send a response whether `dataUrl` is true or not, since the message handler will have returned `true` and the channel will remain open if no response is sent.